# Apache beam pubsub to bigquery schema creation

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My streaming beam / dataflow pipeline is receiving event based data one by one from another service via pub/sub. To ensure that anyone making changes to the data structure upstream does not break the pipeline, I am running the below code on each element:

```py
class CreateLoadsTableRow(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    row = {
      'event_id': element.get('load_id'),
      'domain': element.get('url'),
      'user_data': {
        'event_id': element.get('events'),
      }
      # Loads more keys below
    }
    yield row
```

I am worried that this is going to be very costly - is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Or are there any better patterns?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is basically the same as to parsing JSON per-element: [Apache beam parsing data flow pub/sub into a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57028721/apache-beam-parsing-data-flow-pub-sub-into-a-dictionary/57043335) . In short - this code likely will not be a problem by itself.

Comment: This is not my question, I know this code is not a problem - I am asking if there is a more efficient way to achieve this.